# Reverse proxy for multiple paths to different paths on a single server

Tags: reverse-proxy, reverse-dns

We have several clients who make it very difficult to launch landing pages on their websites - usually enterprise tech businesses with very strict access to their codebase and production site CMSs.

Therefore I'm exploring the possibility of using reverse proxies to allow us to build these pages on a WordPress instance on our own server, and depending on the path on the client site, show specific pages on our server.

For example:

- `www.client.com` is their live site that we can't get access to
- Example URLs would be `/resources/page-1`, `/resources/page-2` and `/resources/page-3`
- These would actually point to our server `/{clientName}/page-1`, etc
- However, they'd need to appear to the user as though they are actually viewing `www.client.com/resources/page-1`

We'd need this to work multiple clients, hence the {clientName} part of the path above.

The questions I have are:

1. Is this even possible?
2. What would be required from the clients' side in order to make this work?
3. What further set up would be required from our side?

I'm not asking for full details of how to achieve each part, just a basic understanding of what is required for each, I will then look at how to implement the details.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to change the DNS entry for your clients' DNS to point to you, and then route the incoming requests to your clients' actual websites. Using a modified man-in-the-middle approach you could modify or inject the incoming/outgoing queries as you see fit. Think CloudFlare; requests are routed through their servers, much like a reverse proxy, to the client and back through again. If the client is down then they display their error message. Take a look at the Squid proxy for starters, though I'm unsure that that is exactly what you want.